# Got an AttributeError when i'm call list.count() function

Tags: python, non-type

I'm solving some katas in CodeWars and in the current kata I'm trying to get how many times an element has occurred in a list that I set as a parameter, then and use it as the range of a  for loop.

However, when I call the function it returns:

```
File "<pyshell#8>", line 3, in delete_nth 
if order.count(item) > max_e:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

here is my code

```py
def delete_nth(order,max_e):
    for item in order:
        if order.count(item) > max_e:
            for i in range(order.count(item) - max_e):
                order = order.remove(item)
    return order

l = [20,37,20,21]
delete_nth(l,1) #except [20,37,21]
```

Comment: Are you programming in the correct Python version?

Comment: `order = order.remove(item)` -> `order.remove(item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this statement
`order = order.remove(item)`
You don't have to reassign list after removing an item.
And also list.remove returns None which the cause of your error.

So edit it to this:
`order.remove(item)`

Comment: long time but it helped me at the time. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing `order` even as you are iterating through it. You should not be doing it. If you want create a copy of the existing list and modify it.

`remove` function doesn't return anything, so, effectively None gets assigned to `order`.

```
def delete_nth(order,max_e):
    for item in order:
        if order.count(item) > max_e:
            for i in range(order.count(item) - max_e):
                order = order.remove(item) ======> order becomes None as remove returns None.
    return order
```